# HTML5 Video not working in IE or Firefox, fine in Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, video

So I have 3 different versions of a video, mp4, ogg, and webm. In google chrome,the video works fine. In IE and Firefox I get a message to say it cannot find the correct file or path.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <video class="center" controls>
    <source src="AlderneyBunkerParty2013.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="AlderneyBunkerParty2013.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="AlderneyBunkerParty2013.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

The website is www.alderneybunkerparties.co.uk if you wish to take a look. I am running the latest version of Firefox and IE 11. I have included a shim in my html also.

I have read that it is fine to just end the files with .ogg or .webm but the files actually end in .oggtheora.ogv and .webmhd.webm - I originally included those exact filetypes in the HTML but I got the same error as I get when they are .ogg and .webm. Cheers.

Comment: This still isn't working. If I need to edit the mime types how can I do that on Godaddy? I have read about .htcaccess but isnt that only for apache?

Answer (score 1):

Try [video for everybody](http://v4e.thewikies.com/)

Code-

```
<!-- "Video For Everybody" http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
<video controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.thewikies.com%2Fvfe-generator%2Fimages%2Fbig-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fclips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de%2Fbig_buck_bunny.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
    <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
</object>
</video>
<p>
<strong>Download video:</strong> <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">MP4 format</a> | <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv">Ogg format</a> | <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm">WebM format</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the video with mentioned formats in correct path ,then only it will play ,try to convert to specific formats and put it in correct path and try or try like this

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf">
  </object>
</video>
```

Comment: I have mp4, ogg and webm. I converted the video and have uploaded all 3 but it's only working in chrome.